# Why is my react/redux function not returning a promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I am in my cart actions and I am calling loadCartItems() from another function within the same file.  However, this function is not returning a promise or any data and I do not know why.  My loadCartItems() function is not even being recongized as a function actually.  Does anyone know why this might be?

```
export function loadCartItems() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch({
            type: types.LOAD_CART_PRODUCTS
        });
        return AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY_JWT_TOKEN).then((key) => {
            return API.getCartItems(key)
                .then((response) => {
                    return dispatch({
                        type: types.LOAD_CART_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
                        response
                    });
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log('Error retrieving cart products');
                })
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("Error retrieving cart items from local storage");
        });
    };
}

export function getUnaddedCartItems() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch({
            type: types.GET_UNADDED_ITEMS
        });        
        return AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY_CART_ITEMS).then((result) => {
            const addedItems = JSON.parse(result);

            loadCartItems()
                .then((result) => {
                    const cartItems = result.response.products;

                    if (this.state.unaddedCartItems.length === 0) {
                        const unaddedCartItems = addedItems.filter((addedItem) => {
                            return cartItems.find(cartItem => cartItem.id !== addedItem.productId);
                        });
                    }
                }).catch(err => {
                    consoel.log('error: ', err);
                });
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('error: ', error);
        });
    };
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.loadCartItems()` isn't a function. `loadCartItems()` is.

Since they aren't in a common class/object/something, there is no need to use `this`. It basically acts like a global (within the context of that file), so just call it directly.

---

Looking at it a bit closer, it looks like you are trying to call an action creator within an action creator. That's your problem.

Normally, you map these actions within your component, so it takes care of the `dispatch` bit for you. However, when you are calling the function directly yourself, you need to also deal with it yourself.

`loadCartItems().then` is the thing that isn't a function now that you've removed the `this`. That makes sense, since `loadCartItems()` actually returns a function, not a `Promise`. The function accepts two arguments: `dispatch` and `getState`.

You need to call it like this: `loadCartItems()(dispatch, getState).then()`.

Comment: Ok I just updated my question.  I tried using it without 'this.' in front of loadCartItems() but it still says it's not a function.  Why??

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't actually say `loadCartItems()` is not a function

It says `loadCartItems(...).then` is not a function.

### What does it mean?

In fact, `loadCartItems(...).then` is not a function, because the function doesn't return a `Promise`. It returns **another function!**

As stated in [`redux-thunk` docs](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk):

> Any return value from the inner function will be available as the return value of dispatch itself.

So, in order to properly call your `loadCartItems()` action, you should do

```
dispatch(loadCartItems(anyParamYouWant)).then(...)
```

I'd recommend you to take a look at `redux-thunk` docs to help you get a better understanding on how thunks works ;)

Answer (score 0):

Both `loadItems` and `getUnaddedCartItems` return [thunks](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk), not promises.

They therefore need to be dispatched first, so that they return the promises you're expecting.

That dispatch code before you return the promise seems to be unnecessary so if you in fact don't need it, just have the functions return the promises.